# Работа с html в Java. Level 1. Фигурные скобки

Tags: java, html, servlet

Имеется задание создать сервлет:
UserUpdateServlet

- doGet URL /edit?id={userId} - открывает форму для редактирования с заполенными полями.
  До этого создавал сервлет для отображения таблицы пользователей и сервлет открытия формы для создания пользователя. Вопрос в том, как мне средствами Java работать с шаблоном {userId} , как подставить ид пользователя вместо `userId`? Файлы .jsp использовать запрещено по заданию, все делаю через `writer`.
  Вот как выглядит метод `get` в сервлете

  ```
  @Override
  protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest req, HttpServletResponse resp) throws  IOException {
  resp.setContentType("text/html");
  PrintWriter writer = new PrintWriter(resp.getOutputStream());
  int id = Integer.parseInt(req.getParameter("Id"));
  User user = service.findById(id);

  writer.print("<title>Обновление пользователя</title>\n" +
          "<body>\n" +
          "<form action=\"http://localhost:8080/items/edit?Id={userId}\" " +
          "method=\"post\" name=\"update\" id=\"form\"\n" +
          "style=\"text-align: center\">\n" +
          "    Id: \n" +
          "    <p><input type=\"text\" name=\"Id\" id=\"Id\" value="+user.getId()+" size=\"25\" />\n" +
          "    </p>\n" +
          "    Name:\n" +
          "    <p><input type=\"text\" name=\"name\" id=\"name\" value="+user.getName()+" size=\"25\" />\n" +
          "    </p>\n" +
          "    Login:\n" +
          "    <p><input type=\"text\" name=\"login\" id=\"login\" value="+user.getLogin()+" size=\"25\" />\n" +
          "    </p>\n" +
          "    Email:\n" +
          "    <p><input type=\"email\" name=\"email\" id=\"email\" value="+user.getEmail()+" size=\"25\" />\n" +
          "    </p>\n" +
          "    <p><input name=\"submit\" type=\"submit\" id=\"submit\" value=\"Сохранить\" />\n" +
          "    </p>\n" +
          "</form>\n" +
          "</body>\n");
  writer.flush();
  ```

Comment: эм,  `/edit?id="+user.getId()+"` не катит?

Comment: я уже пробовал, не получилось. Дело в том что у меня в таблице есть кнопки Редактировать и Удалить у каждого юзера. Когда я жму редактировать , должна открываться форма по адресу /edit... А таблица и форма редактирования находятся в разных сервлетах. И форма не открывается вообще, не то чтобы сохранять юзера с новыми полями. Понятия не имею куда смотреть.

Comment: непонятно, покажите страницу с кнопкой редактировать

Comment: Все, разобрался. Проблема была в неправильном пути к сервлету в web.xml

Answer (score 0):

Просто подставь `id` который ты достал из request'а. Это безопасно, так как это целое число, еще и примитив. Что-то такое будет

```
@Override
protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest req, HttpServletResponse resp) throws  IOException {
resp.setContentType("text/html");
PrintWriter writer = new PrintWriter(resp.getOutputStream());
int id = Integer.parseInt(req.getParameter("Id"));
User user = service.findById(id);

writer.print("<title>Обновление пользователя</title>\n" +
        "<body>\n" +
        "<form action=\"http://localhost:8080/items/edit?Id=" + id + "\" " +
        "method=\"post\" name=\"update\" id=\"form\"\n" +
        "style=\"text-align: center\">\n" +
        "    Id: \n" +
        "    <p><input type=\"text\" name=\"Id\" id=\"Id\" value="+user.getId()+" size=\"25\" />\n" +
        "    </p>\n" +
        "    Name:\n" +
        "    <p><input type=\"text\" name=\"name\" id=\"name\" value="+user.getName()+" size=\"25\" />\n" +
        "    </p>\n" +
        "    Login:\n" +
        "    <p><input type=\"text\" name=\"login\" id=\"login\" value="+user.getLogin()+" size=\"25\" />\n" +
        "    </p>\n" +
        "    Email:\n" +
        "    <p><input type=\"email\" name=\"email\" id=\"email\" value="+user.getEmail()+" size=\"25\" />\n" +
        "    </p>\n" +
        "    <p><input name=\"submit\" type=\"submit\" id=\"submit\" value=\"Сохранить\" />\n" +
        "    </p>\n" +
        "</form>\n" +
        "</body>\n");
writer.flush();
```